# Using Python to match split-RAR extensions

Tags: python, scripting, file-extension

I'm using a Python script in EventGhost to match certain file types in a directory and move them to certain places for other programs to perform actions on them. Here's the entire script:

```
import shutil
import os

SubFileTypes = ('sub','srt','txt')
ZipFileTypes = ('rar','zip','7z','r0')
MediaFileTypes = ('mkv','avi','mp4','wmv')
DownloadName = ''.join(eg.event.payload)
FileName = os.path.basename(DownloadName)
isFolder = os.path.isdir(DownloadName)
eg.globals.tvzip = 'J:\\DL\\TVzip\\'
eg.globals.tvzipdir = eg.globals.tvzip+FileName+'\\'
eg.globals.tvproc = 'J:\\DL\\TVProc\\'

if isFolder == True:
    os.mkdir(eg.globals.tvzipdir)
 #   print 'I\'m a folder!'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DownloadName):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(ZipFileTypes):
                #print 'I\'m a zip file!'
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f),eg.globals.tvzipdir)
            if f.endswith(SubFileTypes) or f.endswith(MediaFileTypes):
                #print 'I\'m a subtitle or media file!'
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f),eg.globals.tvproc)

elif isFolder == False:
    shutil.copy(DownloadName,eg.globals.tvproc)
    eg.plugins.EventGhost.DisableItem(XmlIdLink(23))
#   print 'I\'m NOT a folder!'

else:
    print 'I dont know what I am!'
```

The specific problem I'm having is that I need the ability to match each .rX extension that comes from a split-rar format. These extensions start at r0 and can end at an unlimited number. They are at minimum "r+two digits" (r00,r01,r02, etc) but I think they can get above two digits, though I'm not positive.

Is there some way I can alter my ZipFileTypes list to include these split-rar extensions? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to match filenames ending in `.r` followed by any number of digits:

```
import re

# -snip-

    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(ZipFileTypes) or re.search(r'\.r\d+$', f):
            # do stuff
```

`re.search()` will look for a match anywhere in the string, while `re.match()` will look for a full string match. For this case, because we only care about the file extension, we're going to use `re.search()`.

The regular expression is structured as follows:

- `\.r` - matches a single period, followed by an `r`. The `\` to escape is necessary because `.` means wildcard otherwise.
- `\d+` - matches any number of digits. `\d` represents a digit, `+` represents "1+ of the previous"
- `$` - matches the end of a string.

Put them all together into `\.r\d+$` and you match a split rar extension.

Comment: would `\.r\d\d+$' or `\.r\d{2,}$` be better?  That way '.r1' won't match, because it'll always be at least 2 digits.

Comment: Depends on whether question has a use case where they'll actually have files they don't want to match with `.r1` extensions. It's simpler as is otherwise, and making your regex more complicated just means harder to read :)

Answer (score 0):

use a regex, I don't know how to do it exactly in python but you'll want to match on something like /.r[0-9]*/ should do it as long as you're matching file names.

Comment: That regex would match any filename with an `r` anywhere but the first character.

Answer (score 0):

With the old naming schema, split archives follow this syntax:

> .rar, .r00 - .r99, .s00 - .s99, .t00 - .z99, .{00 - .{99, .|00 ...

You can test it with:

```
rar a -v0.1m -vn -m0 test.rar testfile
```

Windows will prompt an error while it tries to create an archive `.|00`. Furthermore, it doesn't really matter, because from `.rar` until `.z99` there are 901 parts. That should never be reached in normal cases.

But I have seen split archives with `.s[xx]`, so I recommend this regular expression:

```
r'\.[r-z]{1}(([0-9]{2})|ar)$'
```

And for little speed improvements use it this way:

```
import re

#some code

#compile the regex
reg_rar = re.compile(r'\.[r-z]{1}(([0-9]{2})|ar)$')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DownloadName):
    for f in files:
        if reg_rar.search (f) :
            #do sth
```